# How to get FTP file's modify time using Python ftplib

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, ftp, ftplib

I'm trying to load a CSV file to Amazon S3 with Python. I need to know CSV file's modification time. I'm using ftplib to connect FTP with Python (2.7).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### MLST or MDTM

While you can retrieve a timestamp of an individual file over FTP with `MLST` or `MDTM` commands, neither is supported by ftplib.

Of course you can implement the `MLST` or `MDTM` on your own using [`FTP.voidcmd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.voidcmd).

For details, refer to [RFC 3659](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659), particularly the:

- [3. File Modification Time (MDTM)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659#section-3)
- [7. Listings for Machine Processing (MLST and MLSD)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659#section-7)

A simple example for `MDTM`:

```
from ftplib import FTP
from dateutil import parser

# ... (connection to FTP)

timestamp = ftp.voidcmd("MDTM /remote/path/file.txt")[4:].strip()

time = parser.parse(timestamp)

print(time)
```

---

### MLSD

The only command explicitly supported by the ftplib library that can return standardized file timestamp is `MLSD` via [`FTP.mlsd` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.mlsd). Though its use makes sense only if you want to retrieve timestamps for more files.

- Retrieve a complete directory listing using `MLSD`
- Search the returned collection for the file(s) you want
- Retrieve `modify` fact
- Parse it according to the specification, `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS[.sss]`

For details, refer to RFC 3659 again, particularly the:

- [7.5.3. The modify Fact](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659#section-7.5.3) section
- [2.3. Times](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659#section-2.3) section

```
from ftplib import FTP
from dateutil import parser

# ... (connection to FTP)

files = ftp.mlsd("/remote/path")

for file in files:
    name = file[0]
    timestamp = file[1]['modify']
    time = parser.parse(timestamp)
    print(name + ' - ' + str(time))
```

---

Note that times returned by `MLST`, `MLSD` and `MDTM` are in UTC (unless the server is broken). So you may need to correct them for your local timezone.

Again, refer to RFC 3659 [2.3. Times](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659#section-2.3) section:

> Time values are always represented in UTC (GMT), and in the Gregorian
> calendar regardless of what calendar may have been in use at the date
> and time indicated at the location of the server-PI.

---

### LIST

If the FTP server does not support any of `MLST`, `MLSD` and `MDTM`, all you can do is to use an obsolete `LIST` command. That involves parsing a proprietary listing it returns.

A common *nix listing is like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group           4467 Mar 27  2018 file1.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group         124529 Jun 18 15:31 file2.zip
```

With a listing like this, this code will do:

```
from ftplib import FTP
from dateutil import parser

# ... (connection to FTP)

lines = []
ftp.dir("/remote/path", lines.append)

for line in lines:
    tokens = line.split(maxsplit = 9)
    name = tokens[8]
    time_str = tokens[5] + " " + tokens[6] + " " + tokens[7]
    time = parser.parse(time_str)
    print(name + ' - ' + str(time))
```

---

### Finding the latest file

See also [Python FTP get the most recent file by date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8990598/850848#51055995).

Answer (score -4):

When I want to change the file modification time, I use an FTP client on the console.
Log on to a remote FTP ftp *ftp.dic.com*

- *cd* commands go to the correct directory
- ***SITE*** command to move the extended command mode
- *UTIME **somefile.txt** 20050101123000 20050101123000 20050101123000 UTC*

change the access time, modification time, it's time to create a directory on 2005-01-01 12:30:00 **somefile.txt**

Complete example:

> site UTIME somefile.txt 20150331122000 20150331122000 20150331122000 UTC

Please feel free to sit back and wish you a pleasant journey in time :)