# Python - ftplib - Universal file list collector

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I've been working on a Python project. Main goal is to retrieve files (name and last used time).

I'm working on a quite large company and we have dozens of different servers that I need to check.

I've been working with the ftplib to collect file names and last used time but as I'm working with a lot of servers, some of them doesn't accept some fundamental commands like `NLST` or `MLSD`.

So, my last acceptable thing to do is to use the `LIST` command which is returning something different depending on the server.

How should I grab my data without knowing the target FTP server? (like an universal way of doing it)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The "universal way of doing it" is `MLSD` (not `MLSN`). The very reason for introducing `MLSD` (which is was introduced relatively late to FTP – relatively in the context of the ancient FTP protocol), is to have a machine readable format of the listing.

If you do not have `MLSD`, you do not have a *"universal way of doing it"*.

Related question: [How to get FTP file's modify time using Python ftplib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29026709/850848).