# add timestamp in file downloaded from FTP Server using Python

Tags: python, timestamp, ftplib

I have a python script (v3.8) that gets a file once per day from an FTP Server and I want to add the timestamp of the file's creation date at the server when I save it locally.

***My code so far:***

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP(host)
ftp.login(username,password) 
ftp.cwd('/')
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + 'name_of_file.csv', f.write)

f = open('D:/myFolder/name_of_file.csv','wb') 

ftp.quit()
ftp.close()
```

With the above code I save a csv copy in "myFolder" every day, but If I don't add the timestamp , each file will be overwritten the Next morning.

*Desired output:*
**name_of_file_DDMMYYYY_HH_MM.csv**

Comment: `import time; time.strftime('name_of_file_%d%m%Y_%H_%M.csv')`. See also `help(time.strftime)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you share the command line so I can understand what I am doing wrong? Still can't get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [time.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime)

```py
import time
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP(host)
ftp.login(username,password)
ftp.cwd('/')

name = time.strftime('name_of_file_%d%m%Y_%H_%M.csv')

with open(f'D:/myFolder/{name}', 'wb') as f:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + 'name_of_file.csv', f.write)

ftp.quit()
ftp.close()
```

Comment: Great!! That worked. But, this saves the time that my script will run. Is there a way to capture the timestamp of the file's creation ? For example , using filezilla I can see that the file was created at 2am.
I am running the script at 6am, so I want the 2am timestamp to be saved. So I will know if I have a fresh copy or not.
Still, many many thanks!

Comment: That's a different question and it would be best if you post it separately. To get you started, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026709/how-to-get-ftp-files-modify-time-using-python-ftplib

Comment: will do. Thank you