# Identify new files in FTP and write them to AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ftp, ftplib

I'm currently using `ftplib` in Python to get some files and write them to S3.

The approach I'm using is to use `with open` as shown below:

```
with open('file-name', 'wb') as fp:
        ftp.retrbinary('filename', fp.write)
```

to download files from FTP server and save them in a temporary folder, then upload them to S3.

I wonder if this is the best practice, because the shortcoming about this approach is:

if files are too many&big, I can download them and upload to S3, then delete them from the temp folder,
but the question is if I run this script once a day, I have to download everything again, so how can I check if a file is already been downloaded & existed in S3 so that the script will only process the new-added files in FTP?

Hope this makes sense, would be great if anyone has an example or something, many thanks.

Comment: I do not think your question title summarized your problem. You do not have a problem with *"getting files from FTP and writing them to AWS S3"*. You seem to have that resolved. You have problem with finding what files are new on FTP.

Comment: Anyway, this may help you: [How to get FTP file's modify time using Python ftplib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29026709/850848).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cache the fact that you processed a given file path to persistent storage (say, a SQLite database).  If the file may change after you processed it, you may be able to detect this by also caching the timestamp from `FTP.dir()` and/or size `FTP.size(filename)`.  If that doesn't work, you also cache a checksum (say, SHA256) of the file, then you download the file again to recalculate the checksum to see if the file changed. s3 might support a conditional upload (etag) in which case you would [calculate the etag](https://zihao.me/post/calculating-etag-for-aws-s3-objects/) of the file, then upload it with that header set ideally with an 'Expect: 100-continue' header to see if it already got the file before you try upload data.

Comment: Thanks, is there any example code for this?

Comment: There are open source ftp to s3 sync options like https://github.com/vangheem/sync-ftp-to-s3/blob/master/sync-ftp-to-s3.py.  I don't know if they implement the logic you are looking for.