# Downloading the most recent file from FTP with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, urllib, ftplib

I have been trying to write a function with Python that would allow to download the most recently added file (by timestamp within filename).

[image]

You can see that the format has a big timestamp.

What I have so far with the help of forums is the following code. 
In the following code, I tried to sort using the date field (real added date to FTP server). However,
I want to adjust this code so that I can sort the files by the timestamp within filename.

**EDIT** (Tried to clean the code a bit):

```
def DownloadFileFromFTPServer2 (server, username, password, directory_to_file, file_to_write):
    try:
        f = ftplib.FTP(server)
    except ((socket.error, socket.gaierror), e):
        print ('cannot reach to %s' % server)
        return
    print ("Connected to FTP server")

    try:
        f.login(username, password)
    except ftplib.error_perm:
        print ("cannot login anonymously")
        f.quit()
        return
    print ("Logged on to the FTP server")
    try:
        f.cwd(directory_to_file)
        print ("Directory has been set")
    except Exception as inst:
        print (inst)

    data = []
    f.dir(data.append)
    datelist = []
    filelist =[]

    for line in data:
        print (line)
        col = line.split()
        datestr = ' '.join(line.split()[5:8])
        date = time.strptime (datestr, '%b %d %H:%M')
        datelist.append(date)
        filelist.append(col[8])

    combo = zip (datelist, filelist)
    who = dict ( combo )

    # Sort by dates and get the latest file by date....
    for key in sorted(iter(who.keys()), reverse = True):  
        filename = who[key]

        print ("File to download is %s" % filename)
        try:
            f.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, open(filename, 'wb').write)
        except (ftplib.err_perm):
            print ("Error: cannot read file %s" % filename)
            os.unlink(filename)
        else:
            print ("***Downloaded*** %s " % filename)
            print ("Retrieving FTP server data ......... DONE")

        #VERY IMPORTANT RETURN
        return


    f.quit()

    return 1
```

Any help is greately appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT [SOLVED]:**

The line

```
        date = time.strptime (datestr, '%b %d %H:%M')
```

should be replaced with:

```
        try:
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime (str(col[8]), 'S01375T-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.csv')
        except Exception as inst:
            continue
```

try-continue is important since the first two path lines such as '.' and '..' will result a ValuError.

Comment: we don't need all that FTP code. A [mcve] would include the input list and the expected result (output list / item). The rest is just pollution.

Comment: I agree. Sorry for the mess. Will try to clean it

Comment: if all files start with `S01375T-` then get full names and sort them - they should sort as you expect. If they start with different text but the sam length then use slicing `"S01375T-2016-12-01-10-59-03.csv"[8:-4]` -> `"2016-12-01-10-59-03"` and sort this strings, they should sort as you expect.

Comment: if names start with text with different length but first `-` is always before year then use `split('-',1)` - `"S01375T-2016-12-01-10-59-03.csv".split('-', 1)[1]` -> `'2016-12-01-10-59-03.csv'` and sort this strings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python ftp get the most recent file by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990598/python-ftp-get-the-most-recent-file-by-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the list of filenames you can simply sort on filename, since the naming convention is `S01375T-`*YYYY*-*MM*-*DD*-*hh*-*mm*`.csv` this will naturally sort into date/time order. Note that if the `S01375T-` part varies you could sort on the name split at a fixed position or at the first `-`.

If this was not the case you could use the `datetime.datetime.strptime` method to parse the filenames into `datetime` instances.

Of course if you wished to really simplify things you could use the [PyFileSystem](http://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/) [FTPFS](http://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/reference/ftpfs.html) and it's various methods to allow you to treat the FTP system as if is was a slow local file system.

Comment: Hello, The filename is col[8] in my case. Applying date = time.strptime (str(col[8]), 'S01375T-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.csv') results into the error : ValueError: time data '.' does not match format 'S01375T-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.csv'

Comment: You need datetime.datetime.strptime. If that doesn't work try str(col[8])[8:-4], '%04Y-%02m-%02d-%02H-%2M-%02S'))

Comment: It's resolved. Thanks Mr.Barnes, Anyone having the same problem should check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the `-t` option in ftp.dir, this orders by date in reverse, then take the first in the list:

```
data = []
ftp.dir('-t',data.append)
filename = data[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the timestamp from the filename properly.
You could split the filename at the first '-' and remove the file extensition '.csv' (`f.split('-', 1)[1][:-4]`).
Then you just need to construct the datetime obj for sorting.

```
from datetime import datetime

def sortByTimeStampInFile(fList):
    fileDict = {datetime.strptime(f.split('-', 1)[1][:-4], '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'): f for f in fList if f.endswith('.csv')}
    return [fileDict[k] for k in sorted(fileDict.keys())]


files = ['S01375T-2016-03-01-12-00-00.csv', 'S01375T-2016-01-01-13-00-00.csv', 'S01375T-2016-04-01-13-01-00.csv']
print(sortByTimeStampInFile(files))
```

Returns:

```
['S01375T-2016-01-01-13-00-00.csv', 'S01375T-2016-03-01-12-00-00.csv', 'S01375T-2016-04-01-13-01-00.csv']
```

Btw. as long as your time format is 'year-month-day-hour-min-sec', a simple string sort would do it:

```
sorted([f.split('-', 1)[1][:-4] for f in fList if f.endswith('.csv')])
>>> ['2016-01-01-13-00-00', '2016-03-01-12-00-00', '2016-04-01-13-01-00']
```