# How to get files in FTP folder sorted by modification time

Tags: php, ftp

I want to get all files in a FTP folder with `ftp_nlist` function.

But by default it returns an array sorted by name.

I want to sort them by last modified time. I tried to add `-lt` before a  folder path, but it just add date time before each file name.

Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard way to have the FTP server sort the files according to your (or any) criteria.

Though some FTP servers, notably the ProFTPD and vsftpd, support proprietary flags with the `LIST`/`NLST` command to sort the entries.

Both these servers support the `-t` flag to sort the files by a modification time:

```
LIST -t
```

Though this is not only non-standard, it actually violates the FTP protocol.

For all options supported by ProFTPD, see its man page:
http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/ListOptions.html

Note that vsftpd supports only `-a`, `-r`, `-t`, `-F` and `-l` with the same meaning as ProFTPD.

---

If your server does not support the `-t` switch (or similar), your only option is to retrieve the listing with file attributes as is and sort it locally.

For this you cannot use `ftp_nlist`, as it returns file names only.

The ideal solution is to use the `MLSD` FTP command that returns a reliable machine-readable directory listing. But PHP supports that only since 7.2 with its [`ftp_mlsd` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-mlsd.php). Check the `"modify"` entry.

Or, there's an implementation of the `MLSD` in user comments of the `ftp_rawlist` command:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php#101071

First check if your FTP server supports `MLSD` before taking this approach, as not all FTP servers do (particularly [IIS and vsftpd don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49528887/850848)).

Or, you can use [`ftp_rawlist`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php). Though it returns proprietary listing of files, that can be difficult to parse. But if you need to support one specific server only, you can hard code the parsing for that server.