# Python Download Latest CSV from FTP server

Tags: python-3.x, ftp

I want to download the most recent file from FTP server with python. I am able to connect to the server and download all the files in a particular directory but I do not know how to find the most recent file with the specific keyword in the subject.

Following is the code i am using. But it returns all the files with *.png keyname. I do not know how to apply os.path.getctime here to get the latest file.Thats all the help i wanted.
     import ftplib
     import os 
     ftp = ftplib.FTP('test.rebex.net', 'demo','password') 
     ftp.retrlines('LIST') 
     ftp.cwd("/pub") 
     ftp.retrlines('LIST') 
     ftp.cwd("example")
     ftp.retrlines('LIST')
     filematch='*.png'
     target_dir='C:/Users/muzamal.pervez/Desktop/OPD Claims' 
     for filename in ftp.nlst(filematch):                                        target_file_name=os.path.join(target_dir,os.path.basename(filename)) 
 with open(target_file_name,'wb') as fhandle: 
                  ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' %filename, fhandle.write)

Comment: Particularly, see my answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8990598/850848#51055995

Comment: Thanks mate. It really helped to find my way around my whole requirement.